# Анимированная смена картинки ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, анимация, imageview

Мой Xml файл имеет структуру

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_quick_process"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_fragment_quick_process">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />
```

Хочу чтобы во время анимации в Image Полный круг поменялся в наполовину заполненный круг круги это 2 xml картинки, но не выходит

Comment: Вы не показали что вы пробовали и что конкретно вы хотите сделать. Засим будем гадать и предлагать изучить информацию по ссылкам. Например этой: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733140/3212712

Comment: Думаю в словах анимировано хочу перейти от полного круга к его половнике, понятно чего я хочу, я пробовал, создавть отдельный картинки по пути и привязывать их к анимации motionlayout и я пробовал ImageFilterView, но вторя половника все равно видна

Comment: Используйте библиотеки из github. Там этого добра навалом